# how to pass info to a script using url fragment

Tags: javascript, html

Hi am trying to open a PDF.js viewer on my page by passing the filename through a fragmented URL. Im trying to get the script opening the viewer to recognize the filename from the url after #URL_   my code is below. Ive been looking and cant find a solution to this problem and any help would be appreciated.

in the .js:

```
var o:Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(bm.fragment, "&");
var DEFAULT_URL = o.URL_;
```

in the HTML:

```
<a href="../../AAT/Intranet/web/viewer.html#URL_OrderForm.pdf">Order Form</a>
```

Comment: See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#file . Notice that pdf.js is using url fragment to scroll into page or specific bookmark.

Comment: Thanks! can you give me an example of how its encoded using encodeURIComponent() ?

Comment: ?file=URL_OrderForm.pdf